# very high query runtimes in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to teach myself Neo4J by example. Using a dataset of metro stations in my city, I'm trying to find all transfer paths between a set of two stations, as well as identifying both the shortest path and what lines it involves taking.

To calculate the distance, I'm using about 500 location-based nodes I scraped from KML, with weighted edges between nodes classified as PHYSICAL_CONNECTION. The edges have their length and the name of the line they correspond to as properties. The nodes are either TrackPoints if they're rail segments, or Stations if they represent a station.

However, I'm finding that my query times are highly variable- sometimes they take 2 seconds, sometimes on the order of hundreds of seconds, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong through profiling!

Here's my example query:

```
MATCH (startNode:Station{name:"Station1"}) USING INDEX startNode:Station(name)  WITH startNode
MATCH (endNode:Station{name:"Station2"}) USING INDEX endNode:MetroArea(name) WITH startNode, endNode
MATCH p=(startNode)-[*2..7]-(endNode) WHERE ALL (node in nodes(p) WHERE node:Station OR node:TrackPoint)
WITH p AS shortestPath,
reduce(distance=0, r in [x IN relationships(p) WHERE exists(x.distance)] |  distance+r.distance) AS totalDistance
                ORDER BY totalDistance ASC LIMIT 1
RETURN extract(rel in [x IN relationships(shortestPath) WHERE type(x) = "PHYSICAL_CONNECTION"] | rel.LineName) as LineNames, totalDistance
```

Is there some obvious mistake I'm making?

Comment: Please make sure your query has no typos. In the second `MATCH` clause, `endNode:MetroArea` should be `endNode:Station` (or vice versa), or else I'd expect you to get a syntax error.

Comment: Can you PROFILE the query and add the resulting query plan to your question (after expanding all elements of the plan)? That can usually provide some insight into what's going on. You may also want to see if using the [Graph Algorithms procedures](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/algorithms/shortest-path/) can help, as they have a weighted shortest path algo that may work better than just Cypher alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queries with a variable-length path (like `p=(startNode)-[*2..7]-(endNode)`) have exponential complexity [`O(N**d), where N=(relationships per node), d=(depth of path)`].

So, if a particular `startNode`/`endNode` pair happens to belong to a small connected subgraph, then the query will be fast. But if they are part of a large connected subgraph, then your query can easily take a very long time or even run out of memory.

One small suggestion would be to be more specific about the relationship types you allow in the variable-length path (if your data model has unwanted relationship types along the way to the `endNode`). That will help to short-circuit searches along unsuitable paths. For example (if you only want to have paths that contain `STOPS_AT` and/or `ENDS_AT` relationship types):

```
MATCH p=(startNode)-[:STOPS_AT|ENDS_AT*2..7]-(endNode)
```

But a bigger impact should be seen if you can cut back on the upper bound of the variable-length path query. Say, use `5` instead of `7`.